# TCL processing arguments template, why [set argv {}]

Tags: bash, shell, tcl, vivado, synopsys-vcs

Following is a template from tcl wiki [link](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/command+options), this code can be used to process tcl command-line arguments.
I wonder why we need `[set argv {}]` at line 7.

```
# If this script was executed, and not just "source"'d, handle argv
if {[info exists argv0] && [
    file dirname [file normalize [info script]/...]] eq [
    file dirname [file normalize $argv0/...]]} {

    while {[llength $argv]} { 
        puts [list ooo $argv]
        set argv [lassign $argv[set argv {}] flag] ; # Notice Here

        switch -glob $flag {
            -bool {
                set bool 1
            }
            -option {
                set argv [lassign $argv[set argv {}] value]
            }
            -- break
            -* {
                return -code error [list {unknown option} $flag]
            }
            default {
                set argv [list $flag {*}$argv]
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

foreach file $argv {
   puts [format "file: %s" $file]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like the author implemented the performance optimization described in the "Unsharing Objects" section on the [Tcl wiki page for K](https://wiki.tcl-lang.org/page/K). Basically it makes the object unshared, so modification doesn't require a copy to be created. That can make a big difference when manipulating big lists in a loop. In this situation I don't expect it to provide much of a gain because argv will not normally be very big and it is probably only processed once.

Comment: The net effect is to turn the operation (`lassign` in this case) into an in-place operation. It depends on the fact that concatenation of anything with an empty string is specially optimised in the bytecode compiler. It's a ghastly unobvious trick (along with the rest of the `K`-related tricks) and I'm somewhat sorry I wrote it (I believe I'm also to blame for the `K` reference tricks in the first place), but it sure helps a lot when you have lists of millions of items…